# can you use embedded ruby in custom javascript files in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb, unobtrusive-javascript

How does one embed ruby code in javascript for rails?  I know you can do this easily in javascript responders for action methods (for e.g. in create.erb.js). But is there a way to do this for other custom javascript files that are included in the application using javascript_include_tag?

For e.g. in create.erb.js I can write code such as <%= if current_user_name ="xyz" %>

Is there a way to have this type of embedding in a custom js file such as custom.js that is used across the application and not just for generating a response for format.js.

Thanks,

Tabrez

Comment: I had a similar question open earlier but people pointed out that it was too open-ended.  I made changes to the question to incorporate the feedback but it was closed out by then.  So, please read the content before thinking that it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just create an `_application.js.erb` file (name it whatever you wish) in the `views/shared` folder and then include it in your application's layout file.

```
<%= render '/shared/application.js' %>
```

Make sure you wrap it in `script` tags like normal and ensure that you use the DOM ready wrapper within that JS file like you normally would as well.