# How do I make a ruby variable accessible to a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two variables, `<%= @user.lat %>` and `<%= @user.lng %>`

These variables change depending on the user whose logged into my system - it's the address the user gave when registering with my app.

In a `scripts.js` file I've been trying to define them, so my Google map can show with the user's latitude and longitude.

But

```
function initialize_google_maps() {
    var currentlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<%= @user.lat %>, <%= @user.lng %>);
```

etc, etc doesn't work, because it can't understand my ruby code.

I tried defining them at the top of the scripts.js file like:

```
var map_latitude = "<%= @user.lat %>";
var map_longitude = "<%= @user.lng %>";
```

and then using:

```
  function initialize_google_maps() {
    var currentlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(map_latitude, map_longitude);
```

but I've learnt that you just can't put ruby in a js file. I did try renaming it to scripts.js.erb but that didn't work either.

So, how can I define `<%= @user.lat %>` and `<%= @user.lng %>` so they'll be recognised by my scripts.js file, and show up in my maps? I did try this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661366/can-you-use-embedded-ruby-in-custom-javascript-files-in-rails), creating a partial, but it didn't work for me. Maybe I was doing it wrong.

Please note: I can't simply put the code and maps function between script tags in a html.erb file because I'm using some ajax, and things get messed up - the ruby variables need to be recognised by the js file. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to use Ruby in JavaScript file, but it's not recommended so I will not explain how.

To answer your question, you can just put the variable in your HTML attribute:

```
<div id="foo" data-lat="<%= @user.lat %>">Books are coming soon!</div>
```

And then extract it with JavaScript:

```
var lat = $("#foo").data("lat");
```

Comment: Do you mean just define <div id="foo" data-lat="<%= @user.lat %>"></div> in my js file, then map_latitude = $("#foo").data("lat");, and then use the variable map_latitude in my google maps function?

Comment: I mean to write `<div id="foo" data-lat="<%= @user.lat %>"></div>` in your `.html.erb` file. JavaScript can access HTML attributes, so them can be used to pass data between Ruby and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript will get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Those videos were very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think unobtrusive javascript is probably a good way to do this:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript

Answer (score 0):

As the others suggested, you should aim for unobtrusive javascript.

Yet, you might want to use embedded javascript code in a js response for a view, for example. In this cases, you should use the `erb` extension in your javascript files, so the correct is`.js.erb`.